# Larvel Nova Custom Field Class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-nova

I created a custom field in Laravel Nova using the command

```
php artisan nova:field mycode/disabled-field
```

This placed a folder called **DisabledField** in the **nova-components** folder.

I'm now trying to import this field on one of my resources like so.

```
use mycode\DisabledField\DisabledField;
```

and add the field to the fields function

```
DisabledField::make('Product', 'product_id'),
```

When I refresh the page I get the following error:
[image]

**What I've tried**

1. Run `composer dump-autoload`
2. Run `composer update`
3. Run `php artisan cache:clear`
4. Made sure the Disabled field class is in the correct namespace.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

have you compiled your field by moving to the directory nova-components/disable-field and running:

> npm run dev

or production when finnished:

> npm run prod

also import like this `use Mycode\DisabledField\DisabledField;` (not sure if this is important but i always start with uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem neither `composer update` || `composer dump-autoload` || `npm` stuff - didn't work for me. The problem was in my own `composer.json` file, exact in `"minimum-stability": "stable"` row. When you create any custom Laravel Nova stuff (field, tool, card etc.) the new package is created with 'dev-develop' version. And if your own composer does not support dev minimum stability - you will get an error.

In few words, check your composer and:

```
//Change this 
"minimum-stability": "stable",
//to this
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Than run:

```
composer require mycode/disabled-field
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're running `composer update` or `composer dump-autoload` from the root folder of your project not from the folder of the field. That was my issue.